# merge multiple columns in one table?

Tags: r, join, merge

I have a table with several columns, I would like to make a column by combining 'R1,R2 and R3' columns in a table.

DF:

```
 ID      R1  T1  R2  T2  R3  T3
rs1     A    1  NA   .  NA  0
rs21    NA   0  C    1   C  1 
rs32    A    1  A    1   A  0
rs25    NA   2  NA   0   A  0
```

Desired output:

```
ID      R1  T1  R2  T2  R3  T3    New_R
rs1     A    1  NA   .  NA  0      A
rs21    NA   0  C    1   C  1      C
rs32    A    1  A    1   A  0      A
rs25    NA   2  NA   0   A  0      A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
     mutate(New_R = pmap_chr(select(., starts_with("R")),  ~c(...) %>% 
                                                    na.omit %>%
                           unique %>%
                           str_c(collape="")))
#.  ID   R1 T1   R2 T2   R3 T3 New_R
#1  rs1    A  1 <NA>  . <NA>  0     A
#2 rs21 <NA>  0    C  1    C  1     C
#3 rs32    A  1    A  1    A  0     A
#4 rs25 <NA>  2 <NA>  0    A  0     A
```

---

If there is only one non-NA element per row, we can use `coalecse`

```
DF %>% 
      mutate(New_R = coalesce(!!! select(., starts_with("R"))))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
DF$New_R <- do.call(pmin, c(DF[grep("^R\\d+", names(DF))], na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c("rs1", "rs21", "rs32", "rs25"), R1 = c("A", 
NA, "A", NA), T1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), R2 = c(NA, "C", "A", NA
), T2 = c(".", "1", "1", "0"), R3 = c(NA, "C", "A", "A"), T3 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `ifelse` function in a nested way:

```
DF$New_R <- ifelse(!is.na(DF$R1), DF$R1, 
            ifelse(!is.na(DF$R2), DF$R2, 
            ifelse(!is.na(DF$R3), DF$R3, NA)))
```

`ifelse` takes three arguments, a condition, what to do if the condition is fulfilled, and what to do if the condition is not fulfilled. It can be applied to data frame column treating each raw separately. In my example it will pick the first non NA value found.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` row-wise, remove `NA` values and keeping only `unique` values.

```
cols <- paste0("R", 1:3)
df$New_R <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) 
              paste0(unique(na.omit(x)), collapse = ""))

df
#    ID   R1 T1   R2 T2   R3 T3 New_R
#1  rs1    A  1 <NA>  . <NA>  0     A
#2 rs21 <NA>  0    C  1    C  1     C
#3 rs32    A  1    A  1    A  0     A
#4 rs25 <NA>  2 <NA>  0    A  0     A
```